# Save data to xls (vb.NET, Mobile 6.0/6.1)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.1

Hoping someone can help with the below. I have a Windows Mobile 6.1 device. Trying to use it for datagrabbing with the scanner.

I have set up my form, and all the data is input to a datatable/datagrid.
Once the form is closed i want to take the data from the table and save it to excel using excellibrary [(Link)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/excellibrary/). I have this working when i open the .exe on the PC, however its not working on the handheld device.

As soon as the button to export to .xls is pressed it locks up and i get the below error:

```
An unexpected error has occurred in run.exe.
Select Quit and the restart this program, or select Details for more information.

File or assembly name 'System.Drawing, Version 2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A' or one ofits dependencies, was not found.
```

Code being used:

```
 Dim RowNumber As Integer
 RowNumber = 0

    Dim file As String = "..\Data.xls"
    Dim workbook As New Workbook()
    Dim worksheet As New SpreadSheet.Worksheet("Sheet 1")

        For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
             worksheet.Cells(RowNumber, 0) = New Cell(Row("Type"))
             worksheet.Cells(RowNumber, 1) = New Cell(Row("Reference"))
             RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
        Next Row

    workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet)
    workbook.Save(file)
```

If anyone can give some advice, it would be amazing!
Thank you

Comment: what's the problem with your code ?

Comment: That’s what I want to know!

Comment: did u try out ur code ??

Comment: Yes, and I get the error in my original post. So unless I’m missing something with the excel library.dll?

Comment: oke...i'll check :)

Comment: So it seems i was deploying it incorrectly.

Getting another error now, which i assume is to do with the directory.

`Dim file As String = "..\Data.xls"`
`Dim file As String = "%CE5%\Data.xls"`
`Dim file As String = "%CSODL_PERSONAL%\Data.xls"`
not having luck with any of these variations either :(